# How can I increase the number of users of my system?

Tags: .net, sql-server, wcf, client-server

I have a client/server application that depends on MS SQL database for backend storage, the server application is a WCF TCP service that handles the clients requests by selecting from the database set of information.

The service is configured as PerSession and support 500 sessions.
In the client side the user can open different views each view has an object of my service (proxy object) so each view is a session; each view has a Threading timer that requests the data from the server using the proxy object every second.

The application is running good for small number of users with 8 views but when I increase the number a Time out exception occured in the SqlConnection.Open as there is no avilable connection in the connection pool.

There is session/object for each view as the WCF service is not thread safe; it depends on single threaded database access layer that uses SqlDataReaders and SqlAdapters.

Is there a way to increase the number of database connections? it seems 800 is the maximum!! From your point of view how can I increase the number of users?

Shall I change the DB layer and make it multithreaded and make the WCF service single? 
I think this is the bottleneck in the design (can you recommend an article for multithreading in ADO.net)

P.S:

can I replace the database with in memory database or any faster storage?

According to answers:

I changed the backend service to close the connection per method call, but I am facing the same problem as the number of users increases the latency increases (more than one second) , does this mean I have to change the database solution? and what is the alternative solution?.

After that:

I tried two solutions

1. Open and close the sql connection per method call
2. Increase the size of the connection pool in the connection string

But both gives me latency if I increase the number of users, at the same time I monitor the queries in the sql porfiler it seems each query does not take more than 20 milliseconds.

Comment: If you have implemented the supplied solutions and the problem is still not solved then either the connection pooling is incorrectly implemented or their is a problem with the architecture of the WCF service itself. Sql Server can most definitely handle the number of connections, and extremely well. Alternatively the problem lies with the server specifications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After set of experiments I increased the number fo users for my system 800% through set of changes

1. Maximize the connection pool size
2. Create single proxy object for the client and send his requests in serial not parallel
3. optimize the sql queries and use some caching on the service side

Answer (score 4):

Instead of keeping the database connection open for each session, close it at the end of each client call so that the connection is returned to the connection pool. (The connection will not be completely closed when in the pool, so reconnecting it when it's reused is fast.)

That way each session will only use a connection when it really needs it. You should see a dramatic decrease in number of connections needed for a specific number of sessions, and your application should be able to handle a lot more sessions.

Also, as the sessions doesn't hold on to the connections, you will not have an absolute limit on the number of sessions. If there isn't a connection available when a session wants one, it will retry for a while until there is one available. Only if the server is truly overloaded (i.e. requests come in faster than the server can handle them) for a long time, you will get timeout errors.

Comment: I already close the connection at the end of the session but the problem is the number of active session is increased over the time high as the session is not per application instance but it is per view (a graph display form)

Comment: The answer however refers to closing the connection after each client call, not after the session closes. Keeping it open for the whole session is causing the problem your experiencing.

Comment: But this will decrease performance? as for each method call that happens every second I will open and close the connection

Comment: Because the closed connection is returned to the pool this will have  very little effect on performance. Have a look at [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xx3tyca.aspx) article on Sql Server connection pooling.

Comment: Yes, there will naturally be a slight decrease in performance when each database connection is reset. This is what you have to pay to get a vast increase in number of sessions. It's not the performance that is your current bottleneck, but the number of sessions. It doesn't matter how performant the code is as long as you can't have enough users to use the capacity of the server.

Answer (score 1):

One of the best, free online multi-threading books is Joe Albahari's [Threading in C#](http://www.albahari.com/threading/)

Jon Skeet's [Multi-threading in .NET: Introduction and suggestions](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/threads/) is excellent also

Comment: I do not want general article for multithreading, I need it specificaly for ADO.net

Answer (score 1):

Aggressively close connections.  Double check your wrapping all ADO.NET components that implement IDisposible with using blocks or try/finally blocks that call IDisposable and .Close on the connections, commands, datareaders, etc.

800 open connections is a connection leak, unless you someone with  like VISA's or google's number of simultaneous transactions.

Answer (score 1):

I have to agree with earlier posters, you should look into closing connections. In the mean time you can specify a connection pool size in your connectionstring: Max Pool Size

```
data source=RemoteHostName;initial catalog=myDb;password=sa;user id=sa;
Max pool size = 200;
```

Answer (score 1):

Found an article on SQL Server Connection Pooling (ADO.NET) which you might find useful.

[SQL Server Connection Pooling (ADO.NET)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xx3tyca.aspx)